# Why can't I use preprocessing module in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to use the function pad_sequences() but the same error keeps rising: 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sequence''

I have followed Keras documentation and I can't figure out why It does not work. Here is the line of code:

```
from keras import preprocessing
import keras

X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=500)
X_test = preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=500)   
X_test = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=500)
```

None of the above lines seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first line please use

```
X_test = preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=500)
```

You can simply import pad_sequences like so instead

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
```

and replace `preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences` with just `pad_sequences`

Answer (score 11):

in tf version 2.9 it is under `keras.utils`

```
from keras.utils import pad_sequences
```

always search the function in TF git repo and locate the right path.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `X_test = preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=500)` with
`X_test = keras.utils.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=500)`
and using
(from keras.utils import pad_sequences)
keras--v=2.10.2

Comment: it was simple ,yet it solved the problem .ty

Answer (score 0):

In the new version, `from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences` code will show error. So instead of using this, `from keras_preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences` can be used.
So, your code will be:

```
from keras_preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
X_test = pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=500)
```

This will work fine.